# why extrude or move move not moving fluid

Tags: modeling

when I try to move or extrude part in my modeling is not moving fluid is just jump to the next position how I do to rester like before fluid?

Comment: Can you give a screen-shot ?

Comment: Possible you have snapping enabled

Answer (score 1):

If it's happening when you move or extrude, it may be that you have *Snapping* turned on accidentally.  Check in your header bar and make sure you've got it turned off.

It's easy to accidentally turn it on with the hotkey <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.